# json-structure of class-file in Anguar2

Tags: angular

I am using class to control my objects in a Angular2 project.
One of the objects is Case:

```
export class Case {
constructor(
    public Id: string,
    public Sagsnummer: string,
    public Titel : string,
    public Sagsstatus: string,
    public LastChange: string,
    public Sagsbehandler: Sagsbehandler,
) {}
}
```

I use this in my service as follows:

```
caseChanged = new EventEmitter < Case > ();
private case :Case;

getCase(id) {
   //what I would like to do is NOT both have this const AND the class Case.
   //I would like to make the const select from the class Case 
   //instead of writing it again
   const select = {
        "Id": "",
        "Sagsnummer": "",
        "Titel": "",
        "Sagsstatus": "",
        "LastChange": ""
    };
     //params are set to get the specific json-structure from the service 
    let params = new URLSearchParams('');
    let select_encode = JSON.stringify(select);
    params.set('model.select', select_encode);

    return this.http.get(url + id, { search: params })
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .subscribe(
            (data: Case) => { 
                this.case = data;
                this.caseChanged.emit(this.case);
            });
}
```

The variable 'select' to be sent as a parameter should contain the json structure of the class.

So the request URL is the one I want to build.
It should be as follows: 
    https://testsite.mine/api/sag/229c89f9-b083-40bf-afcc-b96aa6fb4b8d?model.select=%7B%22Id%22:%22%22,%22Sagsnummer%22:%22%22,%22Titel%22:%22%22,%22Sagsstatus%22:%22%22,%22LastChange%22:%22%22%7D

I would like to get the content of the parameter model.select from the class Case instead of writing it again.
Any idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Where do you get select the variable and with what values you want it to be initialized?

Comment: can you show the responce.json ? value . Idealy you can map the response to a typescript object .

Comment: I would like the variable 'select' to contain the json structure:    {
            "Id": "",
            "Sagsnummer": "",
            "Titel": "",
            "Sagsstatus": "",
            "LastChange": "",
            }

Comment: Ok I misunderstood it .

Comment: can you show your template and component code from where you are calling this function ? Does this template contain any model . ?

Comment: An example of the GET method to get the case object:     https://testwebsite.here/api/sag/229c89f9-b083-40bf-afcc-b96aa6fb4b8d?model.select=%7B%22Id%22:%22%22,%22Sagsnummer%22:%22%22,%22Titel%22:%22%22,%22Sagsstatus%22:%22%22,%22LastChange%22:%22%22%7D - all I want is NOT to write the same JSON two times.

Comment: I can help on but without looking at your code I cannot tell . in theory before sending the request you need to create a new object of Case class and assign values to it . The you can use JSON.Stringify(objCase)  and then you can pass that string to parameter I hope it will give you the idea but excat code I cannot write without looking at source code .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, that I could make a new object of Case class with the values assigned. I just thought it could be a bit smarter. I updated the code with the const select, that I would like to get from the class Case.